# Cannot listen to contract events with ethers.js

Tags: websocket, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

Trying to track token transfer events but it only works initially when the server is starts. After 5mins, it stops listening to any Transfer events even when the websocket is still active. I've created a sample code for easier understanding.

```
const ERC721Abi = require("../solidity/abi/ERC721Abi.json");
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const wsHelper = require("../helpers/wsHelper");

// this will be initialized when server boots
let _wsprovider 

const subscribeWs = () => {
  const tokenAddress = "0xB7A5bd0345EF1Cc5E66bf61BdeC17D2461fBd968";
  const chainId = 31337;

  _wsprovider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:8545", chainId);
  wsHelper.keepAlive({
    provider: _wsprovider,
    onDisconnect: (e) => {
      console.error(`reconnecting ws ${chainId}. ws connection closed`, e);
      subscribeWs();
    },
  });

  const cb = (from, to, tokenId) => {
    console.log("Transfer Event", from, to, tokenId);
  };
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, ERC721Abi, _wsprovider);
  contract.on("Transfer", cb);
  contract.on("error", (e) => {
    console.error("listenToTokenTransferEvent::error", e);
  });
};

router.get("/test", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    subscribeWs();
    return res.send({});
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return res.send({ e });
  }
});
```

At first I thought it was the websocket that was being dropped off and I followed this thread https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1053#issuecomment-842373187. I've added a `console.log("pong")` in the `keepAlive` pong event to track if the socket is actually closed or open.

Initially when the app starts and I create the contract listener and transfer tokens, it works and prints the log as required. But after 5mins, it doesn't print any thing which means the callback is not called. But the `pong` is still printed. When I terminate the app, `unsubscribe` is printed in the hardhat node which confirms the pong and websocket connection.

#### P.S.

It is a nodejs app with local hardhat node running.

Something similar is https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1053#issuecomment-1381663633 but I cannot do as said in the comment because (add `contract.on` listener in the `open` event of ws). I'm creating a global websocket provider when the server loads and have dynamic contract addresses to track transfer events.

Server log
[image: Server log]
Hardhat log
[image]

#### Update

I switched to `ganache` and its working fine now. I also changed websocket provider to `Web3WsProvider`. I was getting same error for `Web3WsProvider` with hardhat node as well but working with `ganache`
[image: Web3WsProvider log]